# How can I use preg_match() to return invalid characters?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a requirement to prevent certain special characters in specific fields on our site during post (i.e. it needs to be server-side.) I had previously written a javascript function for front-end validation that would check the characters against a regexp as the user typed them:

```
// checks each character one at a time to see if it's valid, returns
// invalid characters:
//      field_name = string containing field name
//      field_data = string containing actual field content
//      pattern = regex
// Returns false if there are no invalid characters
function invalidCharacters(field_name, field_data, regex) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(regex);
    var field_array = field_data.split('');
    var field_length = field_array.length;
    var bad_chars = new Array();
    for (x = 0; x < field_length; x++) {
        if (!pattern.test(field_array[x])) {
            if (bad_chars.indexOf(field_array[x]) < 0) {
                bad_chars.push(field_array[x]);
            }
        }
    }
    var bc_len = bad_chars.length;
    var errMsg = field_name.indexOf('credit card') < 0 ? 'Your ' : 'The ';
    errMsg += field_name + " contains the following invalid character(s): " + bad_chars[0];
    if (bc_len > 1) {
        for (x = 1; x < bc_len; x++) {
            errMsg += ', ' + bad_chars[x];
        }
    }
    if (bc_len > 0) {
        return errMsg;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm now trying to translate this to PHP. Obviously we can't do the check as the user is typing, which is fine, but I do need to be able to check the posted string against a regexp and return a list of the characters that don't conform to the allowed characters.

I'm starting with something like this:

```
if(!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i', $fieldData,  $matches)) {
    // there's an invalid character
    error_log("bad character");
    error_log(print_r($matches, 1));
    $retArray['failedChars'] = $matches; // returns empty array, obviously
    $retArray['success'] = false;
}
else {
    // it's fine
    error_log("it's fine");
    $retArray['success'] = true;
}
```

It does hit the if/then correctly, but how can I return a list of characters that don't pass the `preg_match`? Is there a better way than to loop through the string one letter at a time?

If I enter `ems(%$)` as the string that's represented by `$fieldData`, it should return an array containing the `(`, `%`, `$`, and `)` symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace) to replace every character that you *want*. What is returned will be a string that contains what you *don't* want. You can then use [`str_split()`](http://php.net/str_split) to transform this string into an array:

```
if(!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i', $fieldData)) {
    $rest = preg_replace('/[a-z0-9:_\/-]+/', '', $fieldData);
    $arr = str_split($rest);
}
```

For the string `ems(%$)`, this would produce the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => (
    [1] => %
    [2] => $
    [3] => )
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/166424)

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I must be missing something because it's returning the characters that DO match, not the ones that don't. I'm updating the OP; can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Removing the valid chars was a great idea... +1 :)